# What is the difference between writing self-made activation function as a class and as a general function in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

In the Pytorch official documentation https://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html, it says to write it as a class (ex.(a)), but when I wrote it as just a function (ex.(b)), no error occurred.

I assume there is a difference in back propagation, is (b) still inappropriate?
(Isn't backward propagation done by itself successfully...?)

If possible, I would like to know what is being done (why no error).

ex.(a)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

def mytanh(x): 
        xamp = torch.abs(x)
        xphs = torch.angle(x) 
        xamp = torch.tanh(xamp)
        y = xamp*torch.exp(1j*xphs)
        return y


class NetEn(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NetEn, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(  1, 64, 5, 2, 0)  

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = mytanh(x)
        return x
```

ex.(b)

```
class MyTanh(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, x): #context 状態
        ctx.save_for_backward(x)
        xamp = torch.abs(x)
        xphs = torch.angle(x) 
        xamp = torch.tanh(xamp)
        y = xamp*torch.exp(1j*xphs)
        return y

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, dL_dy):  # dL_dy = dL/dy #grad_output
        x, = ctx.saved_tensors
        dy_dx = 1 - torch.tanh(x)**2 
        dL_dx = dL_dy * dy_dx 
        return dL_dx #grad_input


class NetEn(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NetEn, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(  1, 64, 5, 2, 0)  

    def forward(self, x):
        mytanh = MyTanh.apply
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = mytanh(x)
        return x
```

Advance:

The reason I mentioned this is that I want to do a process in the network that has no derivative...

Specifically, the following code sets the amplitude to 1 for complex numbers (ex.(c)).

Currently, I am working with the idea in (b), but if you could tell me if the method in (a) is appropriate and if you know the correct way to write it, I would be very happy to know that too.

(I can ask again, so you are welcome to just ask the main question.)

Will appreciate any help. Thanks,

ex.(c)

```
def abscut(xcomp):
    xcomp_o = torch.exp(1j*(torch.angle(xcomp)))
    return xcomp_o


class NetEn(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NetEn, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(  1, 64, 5, 2, 0)  

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = abscut(x)
        return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is fine because your operations work with autograd. You would need a class if you wanted to implement custom `backward` logic, use `MyTanh.apply` syntax, or track learnable parameters (as a `nn.Module`).

If autograd works for all your operations, you don't need to worry about the backward implementation.

Comment: I see!
I felt that the key is "if you wanted totrack learnable parameters as a nn.Module".
Thank you very much!!